# Running sed in parallel

Tags: linux, sed, parallel-processing, posix, gnu

I naively ventured to use the following command to process a data file:

```
cat old.one | parallel --pipe 'sed -r "s/\./\,/g"' > new.one
```

The goal was to replace **"."** with **","**. But the resulting file *differs* from that obtained by sequential treatment:

```
sed -r "s/\./\,/g" old.one > new.one
```

Maybe parallel work can be done somehow differently? Here it would be great to do without the semaphores, and combine the parts only at the end.

**Solution**

Thanks a lot! Here is my results:

- sed: 13.834 s

  sed -r "s/./\,/g" old.one > new.one
- parallel sed: 12.489 s

  cat old.one | parallel -k --pipe 'sed -r "s/./\,/g"' > new.one
- tr: 6.480 s

  cat old.one | tr "." "," > new.one
- parallel tr: 5.848 s

  cat new.one | parallel -k --pipe tr "." "," > old.one

Comment: you should post both results and an small sample of your input file (old.one)

Comment: Note you can use `tr '.' ','` to translate between characters, this is faster than `sed 's/\./,/g'`

Comment: Thank for advise. tr works pretty faster.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If this works correctly (-j1):

```
cat old.one | parallel -j1 --pipe 'sed -r "s/\./\,/g"' > new.one
```

then this should work (-k):

```
cat old.one | parallel -k --pipe 'sed -r "s/\./\,/g"' > new.one
```

--pipe is very slow, so if speed is of the essence, use --pipe-part instead with a decent block size:

```
parallel -a old.one -k --block 30M --pipe-part 'sed -r "s/\./\,/g"' > new.one
```

Comment: How to use parallel with a sed command such as `sed -i -f sed-patterns input-files*`?

Comment: @PetrJavorik Ask a question: It is harder to answer well in a comment.

Answer (score 1):

This does not seem to be a problem particularly suitable for parallel processing. However, you could split the original file, process the parts in parallel and then combine the results.